# How to find the number of rounds for the producer to deliver characters to buffer?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

I have a producer consumer program that reads a file char by char and puts the content inside a buffer.

I need help with outputting the number of rounds the producer function made to deliver characters to the buffer. A round would mean one or more continuous writes to the buffer without being interrupted by wait (due to a full queue).

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
This program provides a possible solution for producer-consumer problem using mutex and semaphore.
I have used 5 producers and 5 consumers to demonstrate the solution. You can always play with these values.
*/

#define MaxItems 5 // Maximum items a producer can produce or a consumer can consume
#define BufferSize 5 // Size of the buffer

sem_t empty;
sem_t full;
int in = 0;
int out = 0;
int buffer[BufferSize];
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *producer(void *pno)
{   
    int item;
    for(int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++) {
        item = rand(); // Produce an random item
        sem_wait(&empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        buffer[in] = item;
        printf("Producer %d: Insert Item %d at %d\n", *((int *)pno),buffer[in],in);
        in = (in+1)%BufferSize;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
    }
}
void *consumer(void *cno)
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++) {
        sem_wait(&full);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        int item = buffer[out];
        printf("Consumer %d: Remove Item %d from %d\n",*((int *)cno),item, out);
        out = (out+1)%BufferSize;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&empty);
    }
}

int main()
{   

    pthread_t pro[5],con[5];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&empty,0,BufferSize);
    sem_init(&full,0,0);

     FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
     if (fp != NULL) {

        if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
            /* Get the size of the file. */
            p1.BUFFER_SIZE = ftell(fp);
            if (p1.BUFFER_SIZE == -1) { /* Error */ }

            /* Allocate our buffer to that size. */
            p1.item = malloc(sizeof(char) * (p1.BUFFER_SIZE + 1));

            /* Go back to the start of the file. */
            if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) { /* Error */ }

            /* Read the entire file into memory. */
            size_t newLen = fread(p1.item, sizeof(char), p1.BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
            if ( ferror( fp ) != 0 ) {
                fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
            } else {
                p1.item[newLen++] = '\0'; /* Just to be safe. */
            }
        }

    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; //Just used for numbering the producer and consumer

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&pro[i], NULL, (void *)producer, (void *)&a[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&con[i], NULL, (void *)consumer, (void *)&a[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_join(pro[i], NULL);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_join(con[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    sem_destroy(&empty);
    sem_destroy(&full);

    return 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no way to determine whether the time it takes for a call to `sem_wait()` to return is extended on account of the semaphore's value initially being zero.  The `sem_wait()` function does not communicate that information.

One thing you could do, however, is to start out with a `sem_trywait()`, which will fail instead of blocking if it cannot immediately decrement the target semaphore.  You could increment a counter in that case, and then proceed to perform a regular `sem_wait()`.  Example:

```
int full_count = 0;

void *producer(void *pno) {   
    int my_num = *(int *)pno;

    for(int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++) {
        int item = rand(); // Produce an random item
        int result = sem_trywait(&empty);

        if (result == -1) {
             if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                 full_count += 1;
                 result = sem_wait(&empty);
                 // handle any error ...
             } else {
                 // handle other error ...
             }
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        buffer[in] = item;
        printf("Producer %d: Insert Item %d at %d\n", my_num, buffer[in], in);
        in = (in + 1) % BufferSize;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
    }
}
```

Do note that there is no guarantee there that in the event that `sem_wait()` is called, it will actually block, because the semaphore can be incremented between the `trywait` and the `wait`.  But it does tell you that if a `wait` had been performed *instead of* the `trywait`, then that `wait` would have blocked.  In that case the producer is indeed delayed on account of a full buffer, even if it doesn't spend any of that delay blocked in `sem_wait()`.